# How are we able to do programming in the browser

Tags: browser

I'm seeing some websites coming up with awesome services of being able to do programming in browsers. This is great in my opinion for a lot of reasons. In corporate places, where a lot of things are banned from installing a web solution is brilliant. There's a interviewstreet a YC back startup, where you do programming interview. It's a great startup and I wonder how they manage to get compilers working in browser.

Comment: Not sure what sites you referring to... most likely they just compile and run the code on their server and present you the output.

Comment: But they have all kinds of programming languages available, how do they manage to do it for so many languages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need server hardware to handle this.  I think I've only seen this for interpreted languages.  They'll take what the user is programming and sandbox it from the rest of their server.  One easy way of doing this is to run the language as a script inside of your program.  They take a look at the code the user entered make sure there's nothing harmful inside of it and then execute it.

Some sites that I've seen this done well with are [Rails for Zombies](http://railsforzombies.org/) and [W3Schools](http://w3schools.com/).

The key really is to sandbox it from the rest of your server, so they don't go off an destroy the rest of your server (vandalizing the web page and things of that sort).

The easiest way to execute programs from within another program is with [eval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eval), but it's a huge security risk as the code could do anything with your site.

Comment: Can you explain to me what exactly do we mean by sandbox?

Comment: By sandbox, I mean make it so that the code of your program doesn't operate in the same space as the users program. They are seperate and the user's program will not interfere with your own.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_(computer_security)